# How do you change the point color if it falls to the base line?

Tags: javascript, charts

I have this chart in my web application using **chart.js**. What I'm trying to accomplish is that if the value hits or exceeds that baseline I set, it's point color will change.

[image]

I'm trying to change the point color of those with values **greater than or equal to '9'** or l**ess than or equal to '-9'.**

Here's what I have for now:

```js
var areaChartCanvas = $('#lineChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
var areaChartData = {
    labels: ['P1000001', 'P1000099', 'P1000078', 'P1000011', 'P1000064', 'P1000032', 'P1000002',
        'P1000001', 'P1000099', 'P1000078', 'P1000011', 'P1000064', 'P1000032', 'P1000002'
    ],
    datasets: [{
            label: 'X',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
            pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
            data: [1, 1, 2, -3, -2, 3, 9, 5, -1, -1, 9, -9, 2, -3, -6]
        },
        {
            label: 'Y',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointStrokeColor: '#c1c7d1',
            pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
            pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
            data: [5, -1, -1, 9, -9, 2, -3, -6, 1, 1, 2, -3, -2, 3, 9]
        },
    ]
}

var areaChartOptions = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display: true,
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display: false,
            },
        }]
    },
    horizontalLine: [{
            y: 9,
            style: "rgba(255, 0, 0, .4)",
            text: "max"
        },
        {
            y: -9,
            style: "rgba(255, 0, 0, .4)",
            text: "min"
        }
    ]
}

var horizonalLinePlugin = {
    afterDraw: function (chartInstance) {
        var yScale = chartInstance.scales["y-axis-0"];
        var canvas = chartInstance.chart;
        var ctx = canvas.ctx;
        var index;
        var line;
        var style;

        if (chartInstance.options.horizontalLine) {
            for (index = 0; index < chartInstance.options.horizontalLine.length; index++) {
                line = chartInstance.options.horizontalLine[index];

                if (!line.style) {
                    style = "rgba(169,169,169, .6)";
                } else {
                    style = line.style;
                }

                if (line.y) {
                    yValue = yScale.getPixelForValue(line.y);
                } else {
                    yValue = 0;
                }

                ctx.lineWidth = 3;

                if (yValue) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(0, yValue);
                    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, yValue);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = style;
                    ctx.stroke();
                }

                if (line.text) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = style;
                    ctx.fillText(line.text, 0, yValue + ctx.lineWidth);
                }
            }
            return;
        };
    }
};
Chart.pluginService.register(horizonalLinePlugin);
//-------------
//- LINE CHART -
//--------------
var lineChartCanvas = $('#lineChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
var lineChartOptions = jQuery.extend(true, {}, areaChartOptions)
var lineChartData = jQuery.extend(true, {}, areaChartData)
lineChartData.datasets[0].fill = false;
lineChartData.datasets[1].fill = false;
lineChartOptions.datasetFill = false

var lineChart = new Chart(lineChartCanvas, {
    type: 'line',
    data: lineChartData,
    options: lineChartOptions,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this using this code:

```
var dataset = lineChart.data.datasets[0];
for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
  if (dataset.data[i] > 8) {
    dataset.pointBackgroundColor[i] = 'red';
  }
}
lineChart.update();
```